# Custom query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, crystal-reports

First I am using sql server, .NET and crystal report. I have a table called vehicles contain name, model, price and other data. I want to allow the user to get a custom report by speicfy the vehicle price and the condition( > or < or = ) and get all vehicles that has the same condition.How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Start by showing your work that you've done so far. SQL Query, sample data and expected results.

Comment: use .net to write a form where the user can enter search parameters.

Comment: the search parameters is price and condition. for example if the user enter 2000 int text box and check the < radio button the report will be all vehicles that price is below 2000.

Comment: you can use it in code behind or in crystal report itself using odbc connection. Seems like this is your school assignment

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I did not get any useful answer, after search I got a good method. Not the best but it is useful. First I created a procedure in sql server as the following :

```
create proc get_vehicles
@condition varchar(1),
@price varchar(20)
as

declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

set @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM vehicles ' 

if @condition='>'  set @sql=@sql + ' where price > ' + @price 
else if @condition='<'  set @sql=@sql + ' where price < ' + @price 
else if @condition='='  set @sql=@sql + ' where price = ' + @price  

Exec ( @SQL)

go
```

Then I created a crystalReportViewer file and call "get_vehicles" procedure.

Finally, in button "get report" I take the user choice from radioButtons and textBox and set them into crystalReportView parameters. I answered my question to help other beginners programmers like me.